# Label on checkbox doesn't line up- CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I was trying to perfect my form layouts.

For some reason the labels on my checkbox won't line each other on each checkboxes.

[image]

I am trying my best to make each checkbox label sit to its checkbox using the ff codes:

```
<div class="form-input-group">
    <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
    <div class="checkbox-style">
         <input type="checkbox" value=""> Math &nbsp;
         <input type="checkbox" value=""> Science &nbsp;
         <input type="checkbox" value=""> English &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what went wrong and how I can fix this issue?

You can check the actual site here: http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/test/student-registration.html via Chrome's inspector tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update this css , this will fix your issue , `style.css , line number 1163`

```
.sign-up .signup-form .form-input-group input[type="checkbox"] {
   height: 27px;
   margin-top: 0;
   position: relative;
   top: 8px;
   width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In styles.css on like 1166 (for `.sign-up .signup-form .form-input-group input[type="checkbox"]`), change `margin-top:15px;` to `margin:0;`

Then in style.css on like 1168, for `.checkbox-style` add `display: flex; align-items: center; height: 100%;`

Comment: height: 100% stretches the form extremely long...
Flex makes it stack vertically.
align-items doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to get what you want.  My approach would be to use padding on the parent instead of margin on the child elements.

On line 1163, remove `margin-top` and add `vertical-align` and `margin`:

```
.sign-up .signup-form .form-input-group input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 20px;
  height: 27px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}
```

then on line 1170 add padding to replace margin-top rule:

```
.checkbox-style {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Those changes get you this:

[image]